# How to create verifiable unique hashes to include in any text?

Tags: hashing

Is there a way to include a unique hash along with say any post I make on reddit or any other public forum such that it can be verified by anyone to make sure that the message was posted by me. This is so that in case my password leaks, an impostor can't misuse my account.

The hash that's generated must be unique each time, unlike public private key pairs which are one-to-one unique, because otherwise anyone can copy paste the hash from any of my earlier posts. The aim is not to encrypt or digitally sign the message/post but just to leave a unique fingerprint each time.

Comment: But if the hash has no relationship to the message ... then how would anyone be able to _check_ that it is in fact unique? The attacker could just copy one of your old hashes, delete that post, and re-use the hash on a new post and everybody would think it's unique. _(That is, if anybody cared about your home-rolled scheme.)_

Comment: **All** hashing algorithms (today) have a chance for hash collision.  The chance might be extremely small.  What hashing algorithm are you going to use? Of course, since hashing algorithms by their nature, cannot be reversed, you would be literally just adding something nobody else but you could verify (even then you would have to keep track of what each hash was, and again, the hash wouldn't be truly unique).

Comment: @user1686 am thinking something along the lines of https://wijjo.com/passhash/ or many other password wallets that work similarly. If you follow the link, the site tag could be the date and time stamp and that will take care of the hash having no relationship with the message. That would be secure enough for such a purpose.

Comment: I have been able to get some workable solutions on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/cryptography/comments/nqqw8m/how_to_create_verifiable_unique_hashes_to_include/

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really something out there to do this, so it will come down to creating something yourself.

You need to create a webscript accessible by everyone to verify your post and part of that script has an encryption routine that only works if you enter the correct password.

Your encryption routine creates a hash using a secret method. This could be using SHA256 etc, but does something to the hash so that it is not too large, otherwise a long post would also create an equally long or longer hash, and you don't want that.

Once done, your script outputs what you would put in your post. The user then copies the entire post + hash into your script, presses verify and then knows if the hash matches the content of the post.

Note, if the user doesn't copy everything, for example, they miss a ., they would get a mismatch and may think the post is not valid, so it requires lots of testing.

That said, I don't think many people would even go through the trouble to verify your posts and would only be done in a dispute. So I'm not sure its actually worth the trouble. But if you want to, this is the way to go.

Comment: thanks for letting me know there's nothing out there already. am thinking something along the lines of wijjo.com/passhash or many other password wallets that work similarly. If you follow the link, the site tag could be the date and time stamp and that will take care of the hash having no relationship with the message. That would be secure enough for such a purpose. While I can use this to generate the hash, I'd have to build a verifier for those who want to verify.

Comment: I would use the text of the post itself. What would prevent anyone from copying your text, post it elsewhere claiming to be you, but altering the post? And what would prevent a hacker that has access to your post from just pressing edit, and changing the content of the post? The time/date would not change, so the hash would remain valid but the post changed.

Comment: Every platform records the time the post was made at which would be found to be at odds with the hash upon verification if the attacker simply copy pastes. The editing problem is not as big because a lot of people will have already seen that post and the time of editing will also be captured by the platform. I'd to add another "edit hash" for everytime I make an edit. Some security is I think better than none at all and is enough to act as a deterrent.

Comment: Adding another hash at the time of editing doesn't however make things tamperproof so long as the platform doesn't record the times of edits as well.

Comment: I have got some good answers on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/cryptography/comments/nqqw8m/how_to_create_verifiable_unique_hashes_to_include/